# Opening gnuplot using a bash script file and then plotting a csv file

Tags: bash, scripts, gnuplot

I'm new to gnuplot and scripting and having trouble plotting a csv file.

I am trying to have a user that has a csv file have the ability to plot columns of his choice using gnuplot. This is what I have so far:

```
echo "Welcome Let's get started"
echo "Lets get started with the data set"
echo "How many x-value data sets will be used in the plot?"
read totxvalues #For now we are starting with one data set
echo "What Column in the Data file will be the xvalue?"
read xcolumn
echo "What column in the Data set will be the yvalue?"
read ycolumn
echo "Name of xlabel"
read xlabel
echo "Name of ylabel"
read ylabel
echo "Name of Graph"
read graphTitle

for FILE in "example.csv"*; do
gnuplot
set datafile separator ","
set xlabel "xlabel"
set ylabel "ylabel"
set title "graphTitle"
plot "$FILE" using $($xcolumn):$($ycolumn)
EOF
done
```

I am currently running this script and it gets to the point where it opens gnuplot but it does not enter the variables that the user entered.

Is this the best approach to opening gnuplot and having the user inputs be plotted? The data that will be analyzed will have a lot of data columns and that's why I only want to choose a couple at a time.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is a malformed here-document: it needs to look like

```
gnuplot << EOF
commands
EOF
```

Also, if you want your plots to persist on the screen (using the default gnuplot terminal type) then you likely want to add the `-p` (persistent) option.

I don't recognize the syntax `$($xcolumn):$($ycolumn)` that you have used: I suspect this should just be `$xcolumn:$ycolumn`

Finally I suspect you likely want a shell glob more like `*.csv` than `"example.csv"*`.

So:

```
for FILE in *.csv; do
gnuplot -p << EOF
set datafile separator ","
set xlabel "xlabel"
set ylabel "ylabel"
set title "graphTitle"
plot "$FILE" using $xcolumn:$ycolumn
EOF
done
```

Your script should also have an appropriate shebang at the top i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`